# Buying used laptop - can I change from Win 8 to Win 7 and keep the same license?

Tags: windows, laptop, license, hp-pavilion

I am attempting a purchase of a used HP laptop. The model is HP Pavilion DV7-4120EM. 
The OS that was supposed to come with this laptop is Windows 7, but the seller said that on PC startup, he was guided with installation process and installed Windows 8.

My question is: Can I still replace the OS from Windows 8 to Windows 7 and keep the same license on the computer ? Does one license ( or key ? ) give the option of choosing any of the Windows OS versions ?

I have never owned a laptop before and I don't know how licensing on laptop works. So any extra explanation will do good. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot use a Windows 8 license to install Window 7.  You would need to purchase a Windows 7 license separately.

Comment: @Ramhound - Laptop is supposed to come with Windows 7 license. The guy said that at the repair shop they upgraded it to Windows 8, without asking him first. So can I downgrade back to Windows 7, and keep the license with no problems ?

Comment: Does the laptop have a Windows 7 certificate sticker?

Comment: @JamesC - Which license the Windows 8 license or Windows 7 license?  In either case if you have the license key to both the answer is of course you can.  The Windows 7 license of course will only work on that laptop and cannot be moved to another PC even if its not being used.

Comment: @and31415 - It seems it doesn't. Only Intel Core inside and DirectX 11. But the computer box says among other: " Genuine Windows 7 Home premium ". And now the guys says he installed Windows 7 Ultimate just before putting the ad online. Is it even legally possible ?

Comment: @JamesC It should be located on the bottom of the case or inside the battery compartment. This is what I'm talking about: http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/antipiracy/Pages/COA_hologram.aspx According to the [official specifications](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx%2Fc02521018.pdf), it is supposed to come with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. It should also have a recovery partition to restore the system to factory settings (unless it got wiped or the hard disk was replaced).

Comment: @and31415 - The recovery partition is supposed to be still in computer. Is the Windows license key hardwired into motherboard ? Does this mean I can't expect to have any problems about genuine version of Win ? Thank you.

Comment: @JamesC Yes: "Generally, an end user can upgrade or replace all of the hardware components on a computer—except the motherboard—and still retain the license for the original Microsoft OEM operating system software." For further info, check the [Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx). The easiest way to restore Windows 7 would be a [factory recovery](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01867418).

Comment: @and31415 - thank you. I believe that answers my question. If you want, you can write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Laptop specifications

According to the [official specifications](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx%2Fc02521018.pdf), the laptop is indeed supposed to come with Windows 7:

> #### Operating system
>
> Genuine Windows® 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Additionally a recovery partition should be available:

> #### Storage
>
> 640 GB SATA Hard Disk Drive 5400 rpm
> up to 12 GB partition for system recovery
>
> #### Service & support
>
> Recovery partition (including possibility to recover system,
> applications and drivers separately)

If the computer included a solid-state drive (SSD), the recovery partition might have been missing to save space. If that was the case, recovery discs would have been included.

## The license

When Windows is preinstalled on a computer it is supplied with an OEM license:

> OEM software is licensed with the computer system on which it was originally installed and is tied to that original machine.
>
> After an OEM software license has been installed on a PC, the license may not be installed on or transferred to another PC. However, the entire PC may be transferred to another end user along with the software license rights.
>
> Generally, an end user can upgrade or replace all of the hardware components on a computer—except the motherboard—and still retain the license for the original Microsoft OEM operating system software.
>
> <sub>Source: [Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx)</sub>

In such cases the computer should have a Certificate of Authenticity (COA) label, found on the case. In laptops it's usually located on the the bottom or inside the battery compartment.

## Restore Windows 7

The easiest way to restore a working copy of Windows 7 is through HP system recovery:

> 1. Turn off the computer.
> 2. **Disconnect all connected devices and cables** such as Personal Media Drives, USB drives, printers, and faxes. Remove media from internal drives, and remove any recently added internal hardware. **Do not disconnect the monitor, keyboard, mouse, or power cord.**
> 3. Turn on the computer and *repeatedly* press the F11 key, about once every second, until Recovery Manager opens.
>
> **NOTE:** If the recovery partition on the hard disk drive is not functioning correctly, this method does not work and an error message appears. If an error message indicates that System Recovery cannot be run from the startup screen, a set of recovery discs is needed to perform a system recovery. Follow the instructions listed in the section [Starting the recovery from recovery discs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01867418#c01867418_disc).
>
> <sub>Source: [Performing an HP System Recovery (Windows 7)](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01867418)</sub>

## Further reading

- [HP Pavilion dv7-4120em Entertainment Notebook PC - Product Specifications](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx%2Fc02521018.pdf)
- [Performing an HP System Recovery (Windows 7)](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01867418)
- [Certificate of Authenticity (COA)](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/antipiracy/Pages/COA_hologram.aspx)
- [Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx)